# Resque mail queue installation on Raills

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, resque

I am using [The Resque mail queue](https://github.com/scottwater/resque_mail_queue) job in my Rails application to send mails asynchronously. In the documentation it just says add the gem to your gemfile and add the enqueue method..

I did do that and i see that the mails get added to the redis queue... But the mails are not getting sent, i suspect this is because there are no workers.. i havent worked with resque before, am i missing something?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > Resque.info
 => {:pending=>4, :processed=>0, :queues=>1, :workers=>0, :working=>0, :failed=>0, :servers=>["redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"], :environment=>"development"}
```

Comment: since the gem is still using the resque, I guess you need to do `QUEUE=file_serve rake resque:work`? https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you had a mailer called SiteMailer with a method thankyou_email on it, you could push it to resque with:

```
SiteMailer.enqueue.thankyou_email(*args)
```

And if you need to send it in real time, you can still use

`SiteMailer.thankyou_email(*args).deliver.`